# Add elements to vector - C++

Tags: c++, vector

I can't figure out where is the problem in my code:

```
int n; cin>>n;
int m = 1;
for(int i = 1, j = 2, k = 3; i <= n, j <= n * 2, k <= n * 3; i+=3, j+=3, k+=3)
{
   v[i] = m;
   v[j] = v[i];
   ++m;
   v[k] = m;
}
```

Let me explain: in my code I want to add programmatically numbers in the next order:
1,1,2,3,3,4,5,5...
inside a vector with "n" elements.

Can someone help me, please?!?!

Comment: 1. Please format your code properly so it's legible. Indent it by 4 spaces, or highlight it and press ctrl+k. Also, you haven't described your problem very thoroughly. What's you're specific problem? You said what your goal is, but not the issue you're running into.

Comment: Is it a compiler error or what is happening? Describe the problem.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. You need to show what `v` is and if you gave it enough memory.

Comment: `i <= n, j <= n * 2, k <= n * 3` doesn't do what you expect, you probably  want `&&`.

Comment: @klutt is adds numbers to the vector but it doesn't add them in the order i want. It adds them like this: 1,2,2,2,3,3,3..

Comment: @DannyDSBOfficial [edit] your question to provide a [MCVE] please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want:

```
int value = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 3) {
    v[i] = value;
    v[i + 1] = value;
    v[i + 2] = value + 1;
    value += 2;
}
```

Comment: @cbuchart: And assuming `v` can hold `n` values. With `vector`, it would be `puch_back` and final `resize`

Comment: Point! I didn't mentioned that, but as `n` is an input I'm also assuming that it is straight forward to create the correct array.